# Add property to model object silverlight

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework

I would like to know how to add a property to an entity object from my model.

```
[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="MyObjectModel", Name="MyObject")]
    [Serializable()]
    [DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
    public partial class MyObject: EntityObject
{
private int myVar;

        public int MyProperty
        {
            get { return myVar; }
            set { myVar = value; }
        }
}
```

When I do this, the new property doesn't appear in MyObject but i don't get any error.

How should I proceed to do this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see the `EdmEntityTypeAttribute` attribute, I assume you're modifying the `Databasemodel.Designer.cs` file. As the header of this file says:

```
// <auto-generated>
//    This code was generated from a template.
//
//    Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//    Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
```

this file **is auto-generated and must never be manually modified**. So your property is basically removed when this file is re-generated (probably on compilation).

Just create a new file to add your property:

For example, `MyObject.cs`:

```
public partial class MyObject
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Do note that the `partial` keyword is designed to allow separating the definition of a class in multiple files.

Comment: Thanks, however when do this and then i create a new MyObject mo = new MyObject, i can't access MyObject.MyProperty. It doesn't show in the list of possibles choices.

Comment: @Oliver Please add more background (i.e. post some code: where you wrote MyObject mo = new MyObject, how you defined MyObject, which assembly, which namespace...)

Comment: I wrote MyObject mo... in MainPage.xaml.cs, client side, namespace MyProject.  MyObject is defined in in the web project of my silverlight business application, the namespace is MyProject.Web.Models.

Comment: Oliver as said by Ken the namespace should be the same of what your entity framework class "MyObject" has..